# how to detect which radio button(dynamic) is clicked and how to get the value

Tags: jquery

i have some dynamic radio button, now my problem is how can i detect which radio button is selected/clicked and how can i get the selected radio button's value ??
my code:

```
<div class="well sidebar-nav  rbatch">
<ul class="nav nav-list">
<li class="nav-header">
<?php
  include 'connect.php';
  $result = mysql_query('select * from batches');       
  $index=0;
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
  echo "<label class='radio'>
       <input type='radio' id='".$index++."'> Check me out
    </label>"           
?>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ctFt7/

Your radio button must all have the same name so that at any one time, only 1 button can be selected.

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change',function(){
            alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('input:radio').change(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   var val = $(this).val()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Do something like this:

```
​$(function() {
    $('input[type=radio]').on("change",function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });  
});​
```

View [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WvWCn/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input:radio").attr("checked").each(function()
{
           alert($(this).val());    
});
```